# Socket.io and Express 3

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I created a express 3 app with the express generator and installed socket.io.
On app.js im emiting a message:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('init', { msg: 'Welcome'});
});
```

At server side I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' />
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
        socket.on('init', function (data) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I run app.js It should print "Welcome" on the console, but its not priting anything. I checked if /socket.io/socket.io.js is accesed and it does.

When running the app I get:

```
  info  - socket.io started
Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 200 28ms - 472
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 163ms - 110
   debug - served static content /socket.io.js
```

Am I missing something? I followed the socket.io webpage examples, but it seems that server is running fine... maybe something at the client-side?

EDIT: I also tried `var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1', { port: 3000 } );` on the client side, and also running all socket client side from the body.

Doing a console.log on the io.sockets.on event gave nothing... so "connection" is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a index.jade file to the example I posted before

server.js

```
var app = require('express')()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(3000)
io.set('loglevel',10) // set log level to get all debug messages
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.emit('init',{msg:"test"})
})
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index.jade')
})
```

/views/index.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script.
      var sockets = io.connect()
      sockets.on('init',function(msg){
        alert(msg.msg)
      })
```

Answer (score 11):

app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server)

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

index.html:

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

In your browser's console you should see an object containing "hello": "world".